# Insert Javascript to PHP sheet

Tags: php, javascript

*hello out there i have to implement a jquery task  to one of the Nextgen Gallery Slider Widget PHP output. at least i recognized i stuck in the middle of nowhere because in cause of my experiences.  Is there anybody who can help me with that?*

```
$output .= "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
$output .= "\n  jQuery(window).load(function() {";                
// Shuffle results on random order so even if page is cached the order will be different each time
if($order == 'random' && $shuffle == 'true')
{
  $output .= "\n    jQuery('div#" . $html_id . "').jj_ngg_shuffle();";
}
$output .= "\n    jQuery('div#" . $html_id . "').nivoSlider(";
if(count($javascript_args) > 0)
{
  $output .= "{" . implode(",", $javascript_args) . "}";
}
$output .= ");";
if($has_control_nav && $has_thumbs)
{
  if($controlnavthumbs == 'nextgen_thumbs' || $controlnavthumbs == 'nextgen_original')
  {
    $output .= "\n    JJNGGUtils.wordpressThumbs('" . $html_id . "', " . ($controlnavthumbs == 'nextgen_thumbs' ? 'true' : 'false') . ");";
  }
  if($has_center && $thumbsgap != '')
  {
    $output .= "\n    JJNGGUtils.wordpressThumbsCenterFix('" . $html_id . "');";
  }
  $output .= "\n    jQuery('div#" . $html_id . " div.nivo-controlNav').css('visibility', 'visible');";
}
$output .= "\n  });";  
$output .= "\n</script>\n";

if($shortcode != '1')
{
  echo $before_widget . "\n<ul class=\"ul_jj_slider\">\n    <li class=\"li_jj_slider\">" . $output . "\n    </li>\n  </ul>\n" . $after_widget;     
}
else
{
  echo $output;
}
```

}

id like to add

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
  jQuery('#slider').css({visibility: "hidden"});

 // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link
  jQuery('a.nivo-controlNav').click(function() {
    jQuery('#slider').css({visibility: "visibile"});
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

big thanks for any hints and help

Comment: why JS between PHP?? write on top or bottom of the page

Comment: could you please mention what is the motive behind doing so? do you want to insert the JS dynamically using php?

Comment: as far as I can see i have to write that command directly in the output in matter of the whole nesting. on top or bottom of the page, what i've  tried so far , the browser don't understand the click function and do not make the div on click visible again. because is out of the loop, that is what i think

Comment: ive added  i  slideshow  widget  in wordpress within a post. the div i what to hide at first is part of different divs within the module.
i want to show the thumbnail list  at first  and then on click  the slideshow div.  the thumbnails are depending on the slider div. Therefore i cant use the  hide show  command.

Comment: Is it some kind of new trend to generate Javascript code *in* PHP? There has been so many people doing this recently on SO. Have I missed the boat on some new design trend is is this just stupidity? 8_8

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the thing that you want using PHP Heredoc feature, here is a [simple tutorial on heredoc and its usage](http://wizardsoweb.com/php-heredoc-syntax/2011/05/)
Check this. You just need to replace the message with your JS code. And you are done.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing with this?